# UIAlertController on button click

Tags: swift, uialertcontroller

Opening the `UIAlertController` on button click, the action is going to open but main issue is the `UIAlertAction` methods are not performed on its click. Here is Code block :

```
  class HomeViewController: UIViewController {

        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()

            // getData()
        }

        override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
            super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
            // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
        }

//menuBtn is the button

    @IBAction func menuBtn(sender: UIButton) {
          let optionMenu = UIAlertController(title: nil, message: nil, preferredStyle: .ActionSheet)

        let orders = UIAlertAction(title: "Orders", style: .Default, handler: { (alert: UIAlertAction!) -> Void in
            let alertViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("OrdersViewController") as! OrdersViewController
            self.presentViewController(alertViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
        })


        let about = UIAlertAction(title: "About", style: .Default, handler: {(alert: UIAlertAction!) -> Void in
            let aboutObject = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("AboutViewController") as! AboutViewController
            self.presentViewController(aboutObject, animated: true, completion: nil)

            })

        let contactUs = UIAlertAction(title: "Contact Us", style: .Default, handler: {(alert: UIAlertAction!) -> Void in

            let alertViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("ContactViewController") as! ContactViewController
            self.presentViewController(alertViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
        })

        let login = UIAlertAction(title: "LogIn", style: .Default, handler: {(alert: UIAlertAction!) -> Void in
            let alertViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("LoginViewController") as! LoginViewController
            self.presentViewController(alertViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
        })

        let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .Cancel, handler: nil)


        optionMenu.addAction(orders)
        optionMenu.addAction(about)
        optionMenu.addAction(contactUs)
        optionMenu.addAction(login)
        optionMenu.addAction(cancelAction)

        self.presentViewController(optionMenu, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

Comment: you don't even try to add some print to these methods to see if anything is going on? you need to make controller transitions on main thread, add dispatch

Comment: once try to call this method from viewDidLoad and then check is it working or not ?

Comment: i have tried it even in viewDidLoad method... same problem i am facing... :(

Comment: tried to print... but nothing happen.... :(

Comment: Is your Class and the @IBAction linked correctly in the Storyboard? When even your ViewDidLoad does not fire, it seems to be a different problem. Go to the storyboard -> select your ViewController -> Display the Utilities View -> Go to IdentityInspector -> check if the correct Class is selected ... then please add a Print() statement to your ViewDidLoad() so you can track the changes

Comment: i have linked the button with the correct class... i have checked it all.. even i have checked it adding by Print() command..  uialertcontroller is opening on button click... but the problem is that alertaction methods are not performed on click.... :(

Comment: I have tried my code in another system ... its working fine... dont know whts going on in my system... :(

Comment: have u checked on device yet

Comment: yup.... its running perfectly..... ;)

Comment: then go ahead with it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is code is working fine, I have checked it's opening new `viewController` as well.

Cross check points:

1. Controller class and `stroybaord` are connected
2. `Storyboard ID` has been assigned
3. IBAction must be connected to IBOutlet

Answer (score 0):

On the Button click Action you have to write code.. Try This code.

```
 let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Saved", message: "Selected Frame is Saved", preferredStyle: .Alert)
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style:.Default , handler: { (UIAlertAction) in

        }))
//Add action like this


        self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Still need any help feel free to ask.

Comment: It must be done.. Ok.. Just check you have given the outlet and Action perfectly.If that is perfect than check for the Action Event It must be touchup Inside() in your story board. Tell me you've taken button programmatically or StoryBoard.

Comment: Ok. Then remove outlet and action again. And give again The action must be touch up inside. The problem is not code. It must be in your Action which you are dragging.

Comment: there is no problem in button.... even i dragged it again ... dont know wts happening... :(

Comment: Try again because it should be like this... @IBAction func saveFramePRessed(sender: AnyObject)

Answer (score 0):

First of all check if the button action is touch up inside. Make the button action as touch up inside. Below code works for me. Hope this works for you as well. Change the action title according to your need.

```
 @IBAction func menuBtn(sender: AnyObject) {
    let actionSheet = UIAlertController()
    let criticalAction = UIAlertAction(title : "CRITICAL" , style : UIAlertActionStyle.Default){
        (action) in
       //This section will be executed when the buttons are pressed
        //Do your work here.
        debugPrint("CRITICAL")
    }

    let highAction = UIAlertAction(title : "HIGH" , style : UIAlertActionStyle.Default){
        (action) in
      //This section will be executed when the buttons are pressed
        //Do your work here.
      debugPrint("HIGH")
   }

    actionSheet.addAction(criticalAction)
    actionSheet.addAction(highAction)

    self.presentViewController(actionSheet, animated: true, completion: nil)        
}
```